# How do I call an Activity method once every frame on Android?

Tags: android

I wish to sometimes (when a flag is on) update a few UI components in an Android activity every drawn frame (i.e., not while app is not visible, and not more than once per frame). How do I do this?

Comment: did you try the [predraw listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question specifically states "every drawn frame", which suggests that overriding `onDraw()` in whatever it is that's being drawn will solve your problem exactly.

If that's not quite what you're going for, you should take a look at [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html), which invokes a callback once per display refresh.  You must renew the callback every time it is invoked.  To stop the callbacks when the Activity is in the background, establish the callback in `onResume()`, and set a flag in `onPause()`; if the callback sees the flag set, it doesn't renew itself.

The documentation for Choreographer notes higher-level API features that do common things.  If one of those fits your needs, prefer that over the use of the lower-level API.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use the higher-level APIs but my requirement was really "perform arbitrary updates every vsync" so `Choreographer` seemed the most succinct solution in my case.

Comment: How does one go about "renewing" the callback? I tried doing `Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this);` from inside the callback, but it causes an NPE when I try to set the bounds on my Drawable. Note that calling the same code in a while loop in another thread does not cause any exceptions...

Comment: That should work. If you're getting an unexpected NPE, open a new question and post the exception you're getting with a fragment of the code that's causing it. (Remember that posted code doesn't have line numbers, so you need to indicate which specific line is responsible.) The fact that code works in one thread but not another suggests a problem with thread safety, but you'd need to give more detail to be sure.